# Flutter InkWell: Make splash area larger than the button area

Tags: flutter

I have a custom tile that has a `Row` with two `Flexible` widgets inside. The first one contains a `Text` widget and the other contains an `Icon` wrapped in an `InkWell`.

[image]

When I tap on the icon, the ripple effect only propagates inside the `InkWell` but I would like for the ripple to go through the entire tile. Technically I could just wrap the entire tile with an `InkWell` but I want only the right side of the tile to be tappable. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `InkWell` docs read: "A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.

For a variant of this widget that does not clip splashes, see InkResponse."

Comment: @pskink Do you know how to define a `ShapeBorder` for the `InkResponse` widget that matches the dimensions of the tile?

Comment: post the code of your tile with inkresponse as a child

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the entire tile with an InkWell and using the GestureDetector widget to detect taps on the right side of the tile.

Example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      // Handle the tap on the left side of the tile
    },
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("Tile content"),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // Handle the tap on the right side of the tile
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 48.0,
            height: 48.0,
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes it so that tapping the left side of the tile gives a ripple effect even though it has no action. I want only the button part of the tile to be tappable but for the ripple to propagated through the entire tile.